# Explicit description of the homology of the n-sphere

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, orientation

I'm currently studying the homology of manifolds (so it's mainly orientation and duality questions) and I was wondering how to **explicitly** compute homology of spaces and particularly $n$-spheres.

Indeed, most of the computations of homology groups stem from either **Mayer-Vietoris sequence** or **excision isomorphism**. So, I tried to explicit these isomorphisms but they're actually really complicated since they themselves stem from the **barycentric division** repeated enough (maybe that's the key but I find harsh to visualise in high dimensions).

So here is my question : how can I find a **generator** for $H_n(\mathbb{S}^{n})$ ? And in general, how can I imagine **generators** of homology groups obtained by M-V sequence/excision thm ? How can I explicit the **isomorphisms** that we always use for computations ?

And all these questions arise from the fact that I was trying basic questions about orientation like showing that the $n$-sphere is orientable but I can't even represent myself $H_n(\mathbb{S}^n)$, I don't understand the isomorphisms $H_n(M,M \setminus \{x\}) \simeq H_n(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\})$ etc. Maybe there is no easy way to see it and one just applies theorem without having explicited the objects but I find it easier this way.
The exact thing I can't represent myself is :

> To see the geometric significance of this group, choose a chart around $p$. In that chart there is a neighborhood of $p$ which is an open ball $B$ around the origin $O$. By the excision theorem, ${\displaystyle H_{n}\left(M,M\setminus \{p\};\mathbb {Z} \right)}$ is isomorphic to ${\displaystyle H_{n}\left(B,B\setminus \{O\};\mathbb {Z} \right)}$. The ball $B$ is contractible, so its homology groups vanish except in degree zero, and the space $B \setminus O$ is an $(n − 1)$-sphere, so its homology groups vanish except in degrees $n − 1$ and 0. A computation with the long exact sequence in relative homology shows that the above homology group is isomorphic to ${\displaystyle H_{n-1}\left(S^{n-1};\mathbb {Z} \right)\cong \mathbb {Z} }$. **A choice of generator therefore corresponds to a decision of whether, in the given chart, a sphere around $p$ is positive or negative. A reflection of $\mathbb{R}^n$ through the origin acts by negation on ${\displaystyle H_{n-1}\left(S^{n-1};\mathbb {Z} \right)}$, so the geometric significance of the choice of generator is that it distinguishes charts from their reflections.**

Thank you very much :)

Comment: An approach could be to use the Hurewicz map? Also, the generator of the top homology is the fundamental class of the manifold, when it is orientable.

Comment: The suspension isomorphism is explicit, no? The suspension is what you get when you glue two cones together, and the suspension isomorphism cones of a $n$-simplex in two ways to get two $(n+1)$-simplices. Then you sum all of these together. Alternatively, you just identify $S^n$ with the boundary of the $(n+1)$-simplex and take the sum of the simplices.

Comment: The $n$-sphere is homeomorphic to the space obtained by gluing two $n$-simplices along their common boundary. This isomorphism can be made explicit. Furthermore, the canonical maps of these two $n$-simplices into this adjunction space constitute singular simplices, the difference of which generates the spaces $n$-th homology group. See Hatcher, Example 2.23.

Comment: Thanks for the answers ! I'll be looking in to that :)

Comment: The comment of @Thorgott answers a useful re-wording of your question: Find an $n$-cycle that represents a generator of $H_n(S_n)$. More generally, find an $n$-cycle that generates a fundamental class of a closed orientable $n$-manifold. Even more generally, given a certain topological space $X$, find an $n$-cycle that generates some given class in $H_n(X)$. Algebraic topology books usually have examples and exercises worded in such a manner.